# Is kobuki a holonomic robot?

Tags: ros, kobuki, planner, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all, I am writing a local planner for turtelbot2, i.e. kobuki robot.
But I am not sure is it a holonomic robot. From the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_(robotics))
I think kobuki is a holonomic robot, isn't it.
Thank you！

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188284/is-kobuki-a-holonomic-robot?/) by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2014-07-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, it isn't. According to wikipedia, *A robot is holonomic if the controllable degrees of freedom are equal to the total degrees of freedom.* As a ground robot, the degrees of freedom are 3, the x axis, y axis, and rotation about the origin. But the controllable degrees of freedom are only 2, the linear and angular velocities.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2014-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-07-30**:
I agree, it is not.

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2014-07-31**:
Thank you very much!